# GIT diff giving me different feedback than git merge

Tags: git

when I run

```
git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

it lists a load of expected changes, since I fetched the updated version from my remote.

BUT....

when I run

```
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

it tells me all is up to date!!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have unstaged changes?  Check with `git status`.  And try `git diff HEAD FETCH_HEAD` to avoid comparing with your current working tree.

Comment: nothing to commit, and git diff HEAD FETCH_HEAD still gives me plenty of differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is `FETCH_HEAD` different from the `HEAD`, after a merge?**

A merge creates a new commit, containing all the changes from the original `HEAD`, now `ORIG_HEAD` and the `FETCH_HEAD`.  This means that if your original `HEAD` contained changes not contained in `FETCH_HEAD`, then the new (merged) `HEAD` will be different from `FETCH_HEAD` since it contains those commits as well.

**Thing to check**

It's possible your current branch is already up-to-date with the `FETCH_HEAD` from a previous fetch, for the above reason, or for another reason.

To check this, get the `sha` (hex number) from your fetch head as follows:

```
git log -1 FETCH_HEAD
commit bec5aadef68a5d29c9d523358a0189b86cad4c82
Author: Alex Brown <alex@XXX>
Date:   Tue Nov 16 10:05:19 2010 +0000

    weather report
```

and copy the first 6 digits of the `FETCH_HEAD`: `bec5aa`

next, search for this `sha` in the ancestry of your head

```
git log HEAD | grep "commit bec5aa" -A 5

commit bec5aadef68a5d29c9d523358a0189b86cad4c82
Author: Alex Brown <alex@XXX>
Date:   Tue Nov 16 10:05:19 2010 +0000

    weather report
```

if this returns anything but blank, the `FETCH_HEAD` has already been merged.  Any differences you see are in the current `HEAD`, which may be the merged `HEAD` (or a descendant).

*Example to demonstrate this"

```
cd /tmp
mkdir 1
cd 1
git init
echo "Woo" > a.txt
git add a.txt 
git commit -m "first commit"
cd ..
git clone 1 2
cd 1
echo "Its nice today" >> a.txt
git commit -a -m "weather report"
cd ..
ls
cd 2
ls
echo "Like peas in a pod" > b.txt
git add b.txt 
git commit -m "sayings"
git fetch
git diff FETCH_HEAD
git merge FETCH_HEAD
git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that my local HEAD is actually ahead of my FETCH_HEAD from my remote?

Comment: To check if your `FETCH_HEAD` is already included in your `HEAD`, you can call `git log HEAD..FETCH_HEAD`.  This will show all commits in `FETCH_HEAD` not already included in `HEAD`.  If the output is empty, there is nothing to merge.  Also coonsider using a graphical tool like gitk.

Comment: @MildFuzz - that's one possible explanation for what you are seeing.